# Spring boot get command line args in configuration code

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-environment

I got Spring boot with Spring batch project. Inside my BatchConfiguration I want to get command line arguments so I @Autowire Environment object and try to get my prop but I'm getting null.

After some debug I figured out that I can get all command line args via special property Name "nonOptionArgs" but in this case I got plain string of all arguments passed. Is there some better solution?

Thanks

Comment: How do you pass parameters in command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing everything right with autowired environment. Make sure you pass arguments in the command line with "--"

From [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> By default SpringApplication will convert any command line option
>   arguments (starting with ‘--’, e.g. --server.port=9000) to a property
>   and add it to the Spring Environment. As mentioned above, command line
>   properties always take precedence over other property sources.

Answer (score 0):

you can run your app like this:

$ java -server -Dmyproperty=blabla -jar myapp.jar

and can access the value of myproperty in code.